# Замена src в img на другое значение через JS

Tags: javascript

Необходимо заменить src на другое значение через JS (HTML трогать при этом нельзя). Допустим `<img src="picture/image.png">` стоит на сайте, но вместо picture/image.png должно отображаться picture/picture.png

Слабо разбираюсь в JS, пытался делать вот так:

Начало кода: `var img = document.querySelector('img[src="picture/image.png"]');`, затем один из вариантов:

1 вариант: `img.setAttribute('src', 'picture/picture.png');`

2 вариант: `img.src = 'picture/picture.png';`

3 вариант: `img.src = img.src.replace("pic/jasmine.png","picture/picture.png");`

Ничего не работает. Может быть, проблема в том, что код не вызывается?

Answer (score 1):

#### Уточнение

- Доступ к элементам в JS обычно получают с `id`. Потом находят с
  помощью `document.querySelector('#id')`.
- Преимущество `img` и `HTMLImageElement` в том,
  что у него есть свойство `src` и не надо трогать `setAttribute`.
- При изменении свойства `src` картинка обрабатывается снова и меняется. Доказательство:

```js
document.querySelector(`button#change`).addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
  document.querySelector(`img#view`).src = `https://imgur.com/Qo9CV22.png`;
  event.target.innerText = `Я изменил реальность`;
}, { once: true });
```

```html
<img id="view" src="https://imgur.com/tFKEYxv.png" style="width: 150px;" />
<br />
<button id="change">Я меняю реальность</button>
```

То, что у вас не работает - другая причина. Посмотрите на пример, исправьте у вас.

Comment: Картинки от души :)

Comment: Можно просто написать `true` вместо `{ once: true }`, вроде должно сработать.

Comment: @ΝNL993 можно. Но я привык видеть слово `once`, чтобы узнать, что там у него `true` то. 
А картинки поставил то, что сначала в голову пришло. :-)

Comment: только что [проверил документацию](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), оказывается что это две разных вещи :). Советую вам кстати использовать `textContent` вместо `innerText`, у `innerText` может быть неожиданное поведение, [подробнее на MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

Comment: @ΝNL993 `innerText` я предпочел больше потому что его результат всегда `String`. А `textContent` ещё и может `null` быть. Когда с JSDoc работаешь это мешает. После прочтения документации, мне `innerText` больше понравился))